# Find all $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ such that $b^2-4ac=-20$, and $-|a|<b\le|a|<|c|$, or $0\le b\le|a|=|c|$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, contest-math, quadratic-forms

Find all $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{Z}^3$ such that $b^2-4ac=-20$, and either of the following is true:

$-|a|<b\le|a|<|c|$, or $0\le b\le|a|=|c|$.

---

We see that if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, then so is $(-a,b,-c)$. So far I know $\pm(1,0,5)$ and $(\pm2,2,\pm3)$ work. Are these the only ones? Why or why not?

Comment: Which contest is this from? The conditions look too ugly for someone to want to put this on a contest. Was this reduced from another problem?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

1. $$-4ac\le b^2-4ac=-20\Longrightarrow ac\ge 5.$$
2. Since $|b|\le |a|\le |c|$, 
   $$b^2-4ac=-20\Longrightarrow 4ac=20+b^2\le 20+ac\Longrightarrow ac\le 6.$$

**Conclusion:** What you have founded are all of the solutions of $(a,b,c)$.

Comment: A typo: "founded" should be "found".